# Format ajax success array of data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I want to format data which return from ajax request, to change the status of the buttons to disable. request is send when someone select a date from date picker.

It returns array of data object include time as strings. I want to check each time value and disable the button that have relevant time. I used bootstrap radio toggle button group.

How can i do this with reading ajax retrieved array ?

here is my ajax code,

```
    const $datepicker = $('#date').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });

    $datepicker.on('changeDate', function(e) {            
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/process_date',
    data: {
        date: convert(e.date.toString()),
    },
    success: function(result) {
       console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

function convert(str) {
    var date = new Date(str),
        month = ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
        day  = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return [ date.getFullYear(), month, day ].join("-");
}
});
```

console.log output

[image]

Buttons that i want to change the status disable according to ajax result(like above image)

`         
                            
                                 08:00 am
                            
                            
                                 08:30 am
                            
                            
                                 09:00 am
                            
                            
                                 09:30 am
                            
                            
                                 10:00 am
                            
                            
                                 10:30 am
                            
                            
                                 11:00 am

```
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="8" autocomplete="off" value="11:30AM"> 11:30 am
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="9" autocomplete="off" value="12:00AM"> 12:00 am
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="10" autocomplete="off" value="12:30PM"> 12:30 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="11" autocomplete="off" value="11:00PM"> 01:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="12" autocomplete="off" value="01:30PM"> 01:30 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="13" autocomplete="off" value="02:00PM"> 02:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="14" autocomplete="off" value="02:30PM"> 02:30 pm
                        </label>

                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="15" autocomplete="off" value="03:00PM"> 03:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="16" autocomplete="off" value="03:30PM"> 03:30 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="17" autocomplete="off" value="04:00PM"> 04:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="18" autocomplete="off" value="04:30PM"> 04:30 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="19" autocomplete="off" value="05:00PM"> 05:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="20" autocomplete="off" value="05:30PM"> 05:30 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="21" autocomplete="off" value="06:00PM"> 06:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="22" autocomplete="off" value="06:30PM"> 06:30 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="23" autocomplete="off" value="07:00PM"> 07:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="24" autocomplete="off" value="07:30PM"> 07:30 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="25" autocomplete="off" value="08:00PM"> 08:00 pm
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="timebtn" id="26" autocomplete="off" value="08:30PM"> 08:30 pm
                        </label>
                </div>
            </div>`
```

I also want to know, how the buttons status can change using jquery.
Please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: An image of your code consitutes poor formatting because they are difficult to reproduce.

Comment: how can i format it to a better way?

Comment: Copy-paste your JS code, then it will be easy to edit.

Comment: `function displaytime(data){
 if(data[0].time == "09:30AM"){
  $('#timeslots').find('#4').attr("disabled", true);
 }` i tried this code to disable the buttons, but it doesn't work? what is the problem?

Comment: Copy-paste your JS code where you have posted as an image. Then post it directly to the question

Answer (score 0):

1 To disable a submit button, you just need to add a disabled attribute to the submit button.

```
$("#button").attr("disabled", true);
```

2 To enable a disabled button, set the disabled attribute to false, or remove the disabled attribute.

```
$('#button').attr("disabled", false);   
or
$('#button').removeAttr("disabled");
```

In your code:

```
 success: function(result) {
   console.log(result);
   $("#1").attr("disabled", true); // button 1 disable
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to disable button against ajax returned data. how can i do that? can i use a switch case?

Comment: `function displaytime(data){
  if(data[0] == "09:30AM"){
     $("#1").attr("disabled", true);
   }
}` i want do something like this, but this doesn't work.

Comment: try my code but in success add if(data=="09:30AM"){ code }